# Can't click on links hovering above video in safari

Tags: css, html, ipad, video, safari

So I have a website with a menu-bar at the top with a sub menu that appears when you hover. 
Under the menu, I have a large video playing embedded with the `HTML5 <video> tag`. However, on safari on ipad, i can not click the links that are hovering above the video, despite me having given them an appropriate `z-index`.

Can anyone help me out here? :(

edit: here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7t6c00vn/

The issue seems only to happen on ipad.

Comment: Can you provide an example on here or on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide an example or a link to your site.

Comment: I just put up a jsfiddle

Comment: I don't see any menu and I can click on the link it opens google page, I think the problem is in your menu but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video takes precedence over any other material. Check [Putting Video on Canvas](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html) on developer.apple.com.

So far as I can see the only solution seems to be to hide the video. Check 
[A Solution for Overlaid Elements on Video](http://perrymitchell.net/article/interacting-with-overlay-elements-on-html5-video/)

I would also love to know if there is any other / better solution to this because I'm also in the process of building something using HTML5 and video that needs interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's a sort-of-bug that was fixed with an update for the system. I don't think this problem has a definite answer yet, but I will choose FrankHe's answer as it actually provides some real suggestions and material for the problem.

But yea, things seem to work after the iOS update, so to any end users experiencing overlay problems with Video elements, update your systems! :)

Unfortunately, this also means I no longer have an un-updated device to test on.